# Program doesn't call one function but calls other functions

Tags: c++, function

everything compiles, but when I run the program, it seems to completely skip over the player1 function and goes directly to the printBoard function, when I ask for the variables needed in player1 before the loop, it takes them in and still skips the loop.   I previously had another bool function that worked just fine

```
#include<iostream> 

using namespace std;

char board[9] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
void printBoard();
bool player1(char);
int main()
{
    char m;
    char x;
    char o;

    cout << "Welcome to Tic- Tac- Toe!" << endl;
    cout << "Choose your mode: " << endl;
    cout << "1: Player vs Player" << endl;

    cin >> userCommand;

    if (userCommand == 1) {
        cout << "Player vs Player" << endl;
        cout << "Player 1 will use 'X'" << endl;
        cout << "Player 2 will use 'O'" << endl;

        printBoard();

        while (!player1) {
            cout << "Player 1 please enter space: ";
            cin >> m;
        }

        printBoard();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Player vs AI";
    }

    return 0;
}

void printBoard()
{
    cout << board[0] << "|" << board[1] << "|" << board[2] << endl;
    cout << "-"
         << " "
         << "-"
         << " "
         << "-" << endl;
    cout << board[3] << "|" << board[4] << "|" << board[5] << endl;
    cout << "-"
         << " "
         << "-"
         << " "
         << "-" << endl;
    cout << board[6] << "|" << board[7] << "|" << board[9] << endl;
}

bool player1(char m)
{
    if (board[m] == m) {
        board[m] = 'x';
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: As it currently stands, this code does not compile. `player1` is a function call and userCommand is not declared. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/mowu2m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't calling player1, you're checking whether it (the function) exists. You need to pass parameters...

so it would be:

```
while(!player1(m))
```

(What you have still compiles fine, because referring to a function by name is a valid construction -- it treats it as a pointer to the function itself -- and it gets converted to bool automatically, where null converts to false, and non-null converts to true.)

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: @Dragon I encourage you to compile asking for all the warnings (e.g. g++ -Wall),doing that you are warn about "while(!player1)" and more